# Are ASP.NET Application Cache and Application State storage affected by Session storage?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

If I modify an ASP.NET website's configuration to store session data in a SQL State Database, my understanding is that this will not affect the storage of the Application Cache or the Application State, which are always stored in local server volatile memory.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  Session, Application State, and Cache are completely separate entities.

Comment: Yeah. The documentation didn't *say* they were connected, but I just wanted a sanity check from some one else. Thanks.